# Can't load the inview jQuery plugin using RequireJS

Tags: jquery, requirejs, bower, almond, inview

I'm trying to use the inview plugin within my app, which uses RequireJS to load scripts and is being built / optimised with Almond. I get a console error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'global.jquery.inview')
```

Which appears to come from the shim that require is adding to the end of the inview file:

```
define("jquery.inview", ["jquery"], (function (global) {
    return function () {
        var ret, fn;
        return ret || global.jquery.inview;
    };
}(this)));
```

My require config is as follows:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': '../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
        'text': '../../bower_components/requirejs-text/text',
        'tweenmax': '../../bower_components/greensock/src/uncompressed/TweenMax',
        'jquery.inview': '../../bower_components/jquery.inview/jquery.inview'
    },
    shim: {
        "jquery.inview": {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'jquery.inview'
        }
    }
});
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jquery.inview` is a jQuery plugin. Therefore it installs itself as plugins do, by modifying `$`. When you tell RequireJS that it exports `jquery.inview` RequireJS tries to resolve `jquery.inview` in the global space, which does not work because jQuery is accessible in the global space as `$` or `jQuery`, and not as `jquery`.

You could leave the `exports` out or set it to something that `jquery.inview` does define. For instance, reading the code of `jquery.inview` I see that it sets  `$.event.special.inview` so you could use this in your `exports`.

In case you are wondering, for jQuery plugins the `exports` value is useful only for RequireJS' bookkeeping. You don't yourself access the plugin through the value it exports but through the API it exposes through jQuery.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Thanks for the clear explanation of why too.